# Bootstrap dropdown on navbar doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This dropdown on navbar doesn't work even when I just copying the code from the bootstrap component page. I've tried many solution like arrange the script tag and other thing but still doesn't work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> This is homepage </title>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css');?> ">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">   
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="Brand" src="#">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Here To Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see I already put javascript, jquery and css on the code and its still doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Include jquery before bootstrap js and try again and also include jquery version above 1.9.1 and below 3.

Comment: Thank @Bhansa the problem is within the version of the jquery. I tried changing it to jquery 2.2.4 and its work. Thank you very much

Comment: If your question is answered properly you should tick any of the answers as answered, so we can close this question as answered.

Comment: @Bhansa I've already posted my answer but I can't tick my own answer until it reached 2 days so I ticked answer from Raphael Rafatpanah below. Btw thanks for answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are loading `bootstrap.min.js` before `jquery.min.js` and Bootstrap depends on jQuery.  You will see a error in your console about an undefined function as a result.

Also, according to [Bootstrap's bower.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/bower.json), jQuery version 3 is not supported.  Use version 2.* instead.

Simply change:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I've already switched that two and the dropdown still doesn't work

Comment: I've updated my answer to change the version of jQuery.  Try changing the version of jQuery to `2.2.4`.

Comment: @Lee this one is working, I've already tried that and working. Sorry for my ambiguous comment

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within the version of the jquery. I tried changing it to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and its working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> This is homepage </title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css');?> ">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">   
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img alt="Brand" src="#">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Here To Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know you already wrote about it in the comments above but could you include a comment about what changes you made from the code posted by OP?

Comment: @PakkuDon I know that's why I mentioned in the comment itself, but still he didn't got the solution so I have to provide the snippet.

Comment: @bhansa Thank you very much for your answer. I've already edit my comment above but you already posted the code snippet :D
and I've already posted my answer below